# Explanation on this regex

Tags: regex

Can anyone explain what this regex **^[\x21-\x3b\x3d\x3f-\x7e]*** is trying to do?
Really appreciate your help here.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matches zero or more printable, non-whitespace [ASCII characters](http://www.asciitable.com/) (from 0x21-0x7E; not including `<` and `>`) at the beginning of a string.